# Count of distinct values in pandas column which has list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe column which contains lists of values.
I am interested in getting the count of each distinct value inside the list across the column using python.

Comment: Please provide the sample of data.

Answer (score 1):

To visualize it:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='ColumnName',data=df)
```

too see counts normally:

```
df['ColumnName'].value_counts()
```

Comment: The column contains list values. I need to find counts of each individual value in the lists. 
Your solutions throws an error that list type is unhashable.